# Ruby: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to modify a script to include a case block but whenever I do I seem to get this error. I initially thought it was because I missed an end somewhere but I checked my entire code and it seems to check out fine.

Working (before adding case):

```
 def determine_grade
 Console_Screen.cls #Clear the display area
 #To pass the test the player must correctly retype 3 sentences
 if $noRight >= 6 then
 #Inform the player of the good news
 print "You retyped " + $noRight.to_s + " sentence(s)" +
 "correctly. "
 puts "You have passed the typing test!\n\nPress Enter" +
 "to continue."
 else #The player has failed the test
#Inform the player of the bad news
 print "You retyped " + $noRight.to_s + " sentence(s)" +
"correctly. "
puts "You have failed the typing test!\n\nPress Enter 
to continue."
end
end
end
```

After:

```
 def determine_grade
 Console_Screen.cls #Clear the display area
 #To pass the test the player must correctly retype 6 sentences
 case $noRight
 when 9 || 10
    print "You get an A!"
    end
 when 8
    print "You get a B!"
    end
 when 7
    print "You get a C."
    end
 when 6
    print "You get a D."
    end
 when <= 5
    print "You get an F."
    end
 else
    print "Error"
    end
 end
 end
 end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: **Indentation** please! You'll catch mistakes like this if the errors are visible. Having this all completely disorganized is a huge problem. The second thing is to avoid using global variables unless it's absolutely necessary. Ruby's `$x` is not like the PHP or Perl equivalent where that's simply a variable, the `$` prefix means global. Additionally Ruby style recommends using `no_right`, all lower-case with underscores, for method and variable names, as case has significant meaning in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `end` statements inside of the `when` block.  That's what's throwing the interpreter off.  Also, your multi-value `when` is wrong; it should be `when 9, 10` instead of `when 9 || 10` since that will evaluate to a truthy value.

Remove those and your new code should be equivalent to your original code.

Comment: I changed that and it still wouldn't run, after changing "when <= 5" to "when $noRight <= 5" it runs but now the final output is the error- the original code worked fine.

Comment: Case statements aren't really meant for inequalities.  The best you could do would likely by `when 5,4,3,2,1` instead.

Comment: Case statement are perfectly meant for inequalities in ruby, use `-Float::INFINITY..5` instead of `<= 5` and voilà.

Answer (score 0):

```
def determine_grade
  Console_Screen.cls #Clear the display area
  #To pass the test the player must correctly retype 6 sentences
  print case $noRight
        when 9..10 then "You get an A!"
        when 8 then "You get a B!"
        when 7 then "You get a C."
        when 6 then "You get a D."
        when -Float::INFINITY..5 then "You get an F."
        else "Error"
        end
end
```

Comment: Tried that and now it simply doesn't print out any results.

Comment: It is impossible. You have an induced error somewhere else. This code works perfectly.